# How to get values of nested array of http response by JSON

Tags: android, json, arrays

I am currently working on JSON on android platform. Can anyone tell me how to read complex JSON, any help is appreciated.

I am getting following JSON response

```
{
    "query": {
        "count":1,
        "created":"2011-08-10T06:09:42Z",
        "lang":"en-US",
        "results": {
            "channel":{
                "item":{
                    "title":"Conditions for Las Vegas, NV at 7:53 pm PDT",
                    "lat":"36.17",
                    "long":"-115.14",
                    "link":"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Las_Vegas__NV/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USNV0049_f.html",
                    "pubDate":"Tue, 09 Aug 2011 7:53 pm PDT",
                    "condition":{
                        "code":"31",
                        "date":"Tue, 09 Aug 2011 7:53 pm PDT",
                        "temp":"97",
                        "text":"Clear"
                    },
                    "description":"\n<img src=\"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/31.gif\"/><br />\n<b>Current Conditions:</b><br />\nClear, 97 F<BR />\n<BR /><b>Forecast:</b><BR />\nTue - Clear. High: 106 Low: 77<br />\nWed - Sunny. High: 105 Low: 77<br />\n<br />\n<a href=\"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Las_Vegas__NV/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USNV0049_f.html\">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a><BR/><BR/>\n(provided by <a href=\"http://www.weather.com\" >The Weather Channel</a>)<br/>\n",
                    "forecast":[
                        {
                            "code":"31",
                            "date":"9 Aug 2011",
                            "day":"Tue",
                            "high":"106",
                            "low":"77",
                            "text":"Clear"
                        },{
                            "code":"32",
                            "date":"10 Aug 2011",
                            "day":"Wed",
                            "high":"105",
                            "low":"77",
                            "text":"Sunny"
                        }],
                    "guid":{
                        "isPermaLink":"false",
                        "content":"USNV0049_2011_08_09_19_53_PDT"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tell me how do i get `query.results.chennel.item.title` or `query.results.chennel.item,description`-element?

Comment: Where is the question? I can't find the question? Where is it? Help me find the question! Please!

Comment: first , you have to add some code and show where is the real problem in that, second : take a look about JSONObject and JSONArray in Android documentation

Comment: Here is sample [example](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/587.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`JSONObject`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html). You'll do something like

```
String jsonReponse;
// TODO set jsonResponse to {"query": { "count":1,  ...}}
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(jsonReponse);
JSONObject query = response.getJSONObject("query");
JSONObject results = query.getJSONObject("results");
...
```

Comment: Please tick it as answering your question, then. Also note that you should check for `null` (or add a Try/catch)